# How to get the local path from a file downloaded from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am a bit confused with the Firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

I am trying to download a file from Firebase through the URL of the file and then get its local path:

```
mStorageReference.getFile(downloadURL).addOnSuccessListener(new 
    OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        // I assume the file is now downloaded from the given URL and is on the device
        // HOW DO I GET THE PATH TO THE FILE ON THE DEVICE ?
    }
});
```

The question is in the comments.

Comment: Could you please tell me why does my file name change i.e. from filename to filename-13557732.pdf once downloaded .... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs :-

> The getFile() method downloads a file directly to a local device.

So, instead of doing what you're doing, you can first create a temporary file.
Following is an example :-

```
File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
```

After that, you pass this `localFile` as a parameter to your `getFile()` method ( instead of passing `downloadURL` ). So, when your `onSuccess()` is fired, this file is populated with the data that has been downloaded and you can access it for whatever you need. Something like this :-

```
mStorageReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
      //localFile contains your downloaded data

}
});
```

Note that in this example, the `localFile` is temporary, but you can create a File at your specified path too. It depends on your use case.

Comment: @Camille: the difference between this and your understanding is that Firebase downloads the data into a local file that you indicate. You tell Firebase what file to download from Cloud Storage **and** *where to download it to. It's quite similar to when you upload a file: you indicate what file (or other data stream) to upload *and* where to upload it to. See the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_to_a_local_file